# Is it necessary to include normalize.css and h5bp with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html5boilerplate, initializr

Is it smart to tack on [html5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) (and thus also [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)) to an install of [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/), or will this create a lot of bloat and redundancy?

I'm asking this because [initializr](http://www.initializr.com/) offers it, but I'm not sure whether it will add any extra value to tack these onto bootstrap, since I'm sure bootstrap includes some resets and defaults of its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap's _reset partial is an adapted version of Nicolas Gallagher's normalize.css, so yes, you would probably find it to be very redundant.

Comment: I'm curious, do you know why initializr offers this as an option? Do they just filter out anything to do with normalize.css and just include the extra h5bp files?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but when I click Bootstrap on intializr, the h5bp files are all optional, and I don't see normalize among them.

Comment: That's true. I just assumed it would be there because the docs for H5BP say they use normalize.css: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/doc/css.md.

Comment: So to see if I get your answer: using normalize.css with bootstrap is redundant, but any of the other html5 boilerplate files could be potentially useful when used together with bootstrap?

Comment: Yeah, of those `h5bp optional` files I see, none would be redundant (and therefore all potentially useful) with what bootstrap provides

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Boilerplate isn't only normalize, because it include modernizr wich allow you to style the new HTML5 elements in IE and helps with detecting HTML5 or CSS3 features in all browsers, including earlier versions of IE (before v9). And a httaccess with security rules very useful. I think you can use both, because bootstrap doesn't have all the rules css to normalize a web page HTML.